# Contents are not being displayed from the databse

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

so this is the code to in which depending on the categories suppose a user clicks on a button of the category then all the  events under that category have to be dislayed so this is what i have given as an code for that there are no errors or anything but the data is not being displayed and the last part where the but the last else part is working

```
<?php
global $row2;
if(isset($_POST['category']))
{
  if($_POST['category']== 'Healthcare')
  {
    while($row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {

    } 
  }
  else if($_POST['category']== 'Finance')
  {

  } 
} 
else 
{

}

?>
```

Comment: Please punctuate your question. SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: cool story bro. thanks for the status report.  umm.  was there a *question*?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Where's your database query?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not and still in not phrased very well.  But I took a minute and reworked your code to something more manageable.

Here are some pointers:

First, turn your error reporting on that way your page is showing you any errors you might be getting.

Secondly, read up on using prepared statements for your queries.  If you don't you will be vulnerable to sql injection and xss attacks. You might as well spend the time to understand this now so you don't have to learn this later.  It's really not all that bad to learn. Here is a good link to get you started:

https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Third, if you find yourself using the same code repeatedly you should evaluate the logic of your code. In the case of your blog post html you only needed to write it once and then choose which query you were going to pass over it.

If your going to be using the same post format on multiple pages, make a file with the html and include it in your code and call when you need to use.  This will save you alot of time later down the road if you want to make changes to your code.  You only have to change it in one spot to change it across multiple pages.

Lastly, when problem solving reduce you code to it's simplest form, get it to work, and then add to it until you get it right.

I have not tested the code below, and I am not all that familiar with mysqli but I think it should work.  I mainly just posted this in here so you could see a better approach to what you were probably trying to get at.  Anyways I hope it helps, good luck.

```
<?php
//There is no $_POST['category'] in your form.  The if statement will
//not not show the healthcare or finance queries unless they are set in the $_POST['category'].
if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category']){

    $query = "select * from event where category = ? "; //<--Uses a palceholder for the category.

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); //<--Prepares the query.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['category']); //<--Binds the category placeholder. 
    $stmt->execute(); //<--Runs the query.
    $results = $stmt->get_results(); //<-- Gets the results and holds them in $results.

} else {

    //The shows everything query
    $query = "select * from event";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $results = $stmt->get_results();

 }

//The all your inputs have to be inside your form tag.
//Put the form tag first.   
echo

'<form action="eventdetail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="events events-full event-list">

    <div class="container">';

    if($results){  //<--Check to see if the query has any data.

        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){  //<--Uses the results and generates an array
      //containing the results.

        //Loop over your html. Echos out one row for each iteration of the loop.
            echo
            '<div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8"> 

                        <!--Blog Post Start-->

                            <div class="blog-post">

                                <div class="post-thumb">

                                    <div class="link-wrap"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a> </div>

                                    <img src="images/gallery/' . $row['event_image'] . '" alt="user">

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="event-text">

                                        <div class="event-counter">
                                        </div>

                                        <h4> <a href="#">' . $row['title'] . '</a> </h4>
                                        <p>'  . $row['descrption'] . '</p>

                                        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">' . $row['location'] . '</span></p>
                                        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain">' . $row['organizer'] . '</span></p>
                                        <a class="nd" href="">

                                        <input type="hidden" value="' . $row['id'] . '" name="' . $row['id'] . '"/> 

                                    </div>

                                </div>  
                          </div>
                    </div>

            </div>';

        }

    }else{

        echo 'Your query did not find any results.';

    }

echo 
    '</div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="detail" value="detail">Event Detail</button>

</form>'; //<--Close the from tag.
```